# Get a QuerySet and order it by sum of values of relative table

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm developing an reputation app, and try to get users dict ordered by reputation points. I've got a standard user-table, and relative AuthUserKarma table to store a accrued points.

```
class AuthUserKarma(models.Model):
user_ref = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user_ref', blank=True, null=True,related_name="karma")
points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
forwhat = models.CharField(max_length=255)
module_ref = models.ForeignKey('Modules', db_column='module_ref')
datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

To get a sum of accrued points bu a user I use a User-model procedure:

```
def points(self):
    from django.db.models import Sum
    return self.karma.aggregate(Sum('points'))['points__sum'] or '0'
```

How can I get a QuerySet or a dict with users are sorted by they carma-points?

Comment: But one user seems to have many AuthUserKarma instances. What's the expected result exactly?

Comment: Yes, user do some activities on the site and get points for each activity. For example: "10 karma points for petition add" or "-10 for deleted comment by moderator". Sum of this points is a user-rating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate `User` objects to include the sum of points, and then order using this information:

```
User.objects.annotate(points_sum=Sum('karma__points')).order_by('points_sum')
```

This has the additional benefit of retrieving the sums for all users in a single database query.